# Selecting from a dataframe with duplicate index

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and pandas. 
I have a datetime indexed dataframe. I want to select rows for which the time is > 08:00:00
I tried using pd.DataFrame.select function. It is failing because the index has duplicate entries.

Am I trying it correctly?

Is there a way around it?

Is it a bad practice to have data indexed with duplicate entries?

```
>>> df.head(10)
                            A
time                         
1900-01-01 00:01:01.456170  0
1900-01-01 00:01:01.969600  0
1900-01-01 00:01:04.305494  0
1900-01-01 00:01:13.860365  0
1900-01-01 00:01:19.666371  0
1900-01-01 00:01:24.920744  0
1900-01-01 00:01:24.931466  0
1900-01-01 00:02:07.522741  0
1900-01-01 00:02:13.857793  0
1900-01-01 00:02:34.817765 -7
>>> timeindexvalid = lambda x : x.to_datetime() > datetime(1900, 1, 1, 8)
>>> df.select(timeindexvalid)
Traceback (most recent call last):

    raise Exception('Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index '
Exception: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an expression to select the indices you want without using `select()`:

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]:
            A
time
2012-05-01  0
2012-05-02  1
2012-05-02  2

In [2]: df.index
Out[2]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>

In [3]: df.index.is_unique
Out[3]: False

In [4]: df[df.index > datetime(2012,5,1)]
Out[4]:
            A
time
2012-05-02  1
2012-05-02  2
```

Replicating your error using select:

```
In [5]: sel = lambda x: x > datetime(2012,5,1)

In [6]: df.select(sel)
Exception: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Comment: I think so.  The traceback kicks of the exception from this function: `get_indexer()`.

Comment: would it mean that expression based selection can be a little faster, while the 'select' based selection is a more generic?

Answer (score 1):

I made a note on GitHub to support this more easily with the `between_time` method:

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2826

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexer_between_time` (here between 1min past midnight and 2min past):

```
In [11]: df1.iloc[df1.index.indexer_between_time('00:01:00', '00:02:00')]
Out[11]:
                            A
time
1900-01-01 00:01:01.456170  0
1900-01-01 00:01:01.969600  0
1900-01-01 00:01:04.305494  0
1900-01-01 00:01:13.860365  0
1900-01-01 00:01:19.666371  0
1900-01-01 00:01:24.920744  0
1900-01-01 00:01:24.931466  0
```